# Tagging methods in a module for reference from mixing-classes

Tags: ruby, module, metaprogramming, class-method, instance-methods

I have a module `M` which I want to tag specific methods as "special", in such a way that classes which mix in this module can check whether a given method name is special. This is what I've tried:

```
module M
  def specials
    @specials ||= {}
  end

  def self.special name
    specials[name] = true
  end

  def is_special? name
    specials[name]
  end

  def meth1
    ...
  end
  special :meth1
end

class C
  include M

  def check name
    is_special? name
  end
end
```

Of course this doesn't work, because I can't call an instance method from the class method `self.special`. I suspect that if I want to keep the feature of being able to call `special :<name>` below the wanted methods in the module, I have no choice but to use class variables (e.g. `@@specials`) Can somebody prove me wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can make all these methods class methods and do the following:

```
module M
  def self.specials
    @specials ||= {}
  end

  def self.special name
    self.specials[name] = true
  end

  def self.is_special? name
    self.specials[name]
  end

  def meth1
    'foo'
  end

  def meth2
    'bar'
  end

  special :meth1
end

class C
  include M

  def check name
    M.is_special? name
  end
end

p C.new.check(:meth1)
#=> true
p C.new.check(:meth2)
#=> nil
```

Not sure if that would work for you.